# How should I replace parts from a text file through Python?

Tags: python, file-io, replace

Okay, so here's the deal, folks:

I've been experimenting with Python(3.3), trying to create a python program capable of generating random names for weapons in a game and replacing their old names, which are located inside a text file. Here's my function:

```
def ModifyFile(shareddottxt):
  global name
  a = open(str(shareddottxt) , 'r')
  b = a.read()
  namefix1 = '''SWEP.PrintName          = "'''
  namefix2 = '''"               //sgaardname'''
  name1 = b.find(namefix1) + len(namefix1)
  name2 = b.find(namefix2, name1)
  name = name + b[name1:name2]        ## We got our weapon's name! Let's add the suffix.
  c = open((shareddottxt + ".lua"), 'r+')
  for line in b:
    c.write(line.replace(name, (name + namesuffix)))
  c.close()
  a.close
```

As you can see, I first open my text file to find the weapon's name. After that, I try to create a new file and copy the contents from the old one, while replacing the weapon's name for (name + namesuffix). However, after calling the function, I get nothing. No file whatsoever. And even if I DO add the file to the folder manually, it does not change. At all.

Namesuffix is generated through another function early on. It is saved as a global var.

Also, my text file is huge, but the bit I'm trying to edit is:

```
SWEP.PrintName          = "KI Stinger 9mm"     //sgaardname
```

The expected result:

```
SWEP.PrintName          = "KI Stinger 9mm NAMESUFFIX"     //sgaardname
```

Where did I mess up, guys?

Comment: where have you assigned the variable 'namesuffix'?

Comment: better add how input file looks and whats the desired output

Comment: You see, I have a function that generates the var 'namesuffix'. That one works just fine. So the gun should end up with a name like "KI Stinger 9mm V4+Spc".  Also, I have added the line I wish to change from my text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this is more pythonic.

```
def replace_in_file(filename, oldtext, newtext):
    with open(filename, 'r+') as file:
        lines = file.read()
        new_lines = lines.replace(oldtext, newtext)
        file.seek(0)
        file.write(new_lines)
```

If you don't want to replace that file

```
def replace_in_file(filename, oldtext, newtext):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file, open(filename + ".temp", 'w') as temp:
        lines = file.read()
        new_lines = lines.replace(oldtext, newtext)
        temp.write(new_lines)
```

Comment: I tried calling your function inside my function, but I still end up with the default text file.

Comment: If you use the second function look for a ".temp" file in the same folder. The first function will just replace the name in the same file. All you should have to do is replace the ".temp" with ".lua" in the second function.

Comment: Nevermind! Turns out it DID edit the file, I just forgot to reload the file :v  Cheers, mate!